# How to fix 'Failure in `windows_configure_web_node.py FileNotFoundError`

Tags: python, windows-machine-learning

I'm trying to configure Microsoft Machine Learning Server (9.4) to work on my local computer.

I'm getting stuck at following this instruction:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/operationalize/configure-machine-learning-server-one-box

at

```
# With elevated privileges, run the following commands.
# Set up both nodes on one machine
 az mlserver admin node setup --onebox --admin-password <Password> --confirm-password <Password>
```

I have tried to reinstall the machine learning server (not including R), same results.

This is the error message that is shown when trying to configure the machine learning server:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>az mlserver admin bootstrap
Admin password:
Confirm admin password:
fail The web node failed to be configured.
Failure in `windows_configure_web_node.py` FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
fail The compute node failed to be configured.
Failure in `windows_configure_compute_node.py` FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
The web node failed to be configured.
Failure in `windows_configure_web_node.py` FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
The compute node failed to be configured.
Failure in `windows_configure_compute_node.py` FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Has someone else already encountered/solved that issue?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for my problems.

My system could not find `powershell.exe`, as it was not added to the `PATH` environment variable.

By adding a reference to

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

I could get the server up and running.